# C++ Templates std::array<char16_t, N> hide N to template impl?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I'm thinking about creating an in memory Unicode Character database (ucd) in C++. To store the codepoint for e.g. UTF-16 the container must be:

- small in memory size: No `std::vector`, `std::string` etc...
- have both randomaccess to its codeunits and the data aligned as a whole.
- must be fast comparable
- must have compile time flexible size for codepoints with surrogates

To container that comes close is `std::array<char16_t, N>`. But I want to hide the `N` by filling it using a constructor with parameter pack:

```
#include <array>
#include <utility>

template <typename CUT>
struct ucodepoint_storage
{
    typedef typename CUT         value_type;
    typedef unsigned char        size_type;

    template <size_type N>
    struct sizer
    {
        static constexpr size_type units = N;
        static constexpr size_type bytes = (N * sizeof(value_type));
    };

    using sizer_type = sizer<1>;

    template<typename... Chars>
    constexpr ucodepoint_storage(Chars&&... chars)
    : m_arrData(std::move(std::array<value_type, sizeof...(chars)>{ chars... }))
    {
        using sizer_type = sizer<sizeof...(chars)>;
    }

private:
    const std::array<value_type, sizer_type::units>     m_arrData;
};
```

Above does not compile when amount of args does not match the default 1.

Is this possible? Everything is compile time known and it looks like different types of same member just is not possible. I see it as a pImpl idiom without the pointers because they will also take up to much memory on my 64 bits machine.

Comment: The Unicode character database is *gigantic*; the 24-byte overhead of a `vector` or `string` is *trivial* by comparison. Your entire approach to storing the UCD is wrongheaded.

Comment: I concur with @NicolBolas. It's not like creating one storage per a character. How many storages do you plan to have vs the average load? Are you sure this optimization is worth it? I still find it an interesting question, but rather academical.

Comment: You could always have the class accept `N` as a template parameter, then provide a `make_ucodepoint_storage()` function that takes a parameter pack, determines `N` from it, and returns the appropriate object.  Probably still better to just use one of the standard library types, though.

Comment: Thanks for quick response! For unicode 9.0, which is 128,172 characters (http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode9.0.0/ )  x sizeof(char32_t) = 512688 bytes / 0,5 Mb for identifying only. The rest will be the pain: blocks, properties and stuff. But I like a challenge :-)

Comment: @HenryRoeland I think you are confusing things. Which coding uses 8 bytes? UTF-8 uses up to 32 *bits* per character, and UTF-8 with with plain latin characters is an eqivalent of ASCII... And the more content for storage you have the less it's overhead means. You sound like "I have `{kilo, mega, giga}` bytes of data to store so I need to strip 4bytes from my container to save space."

Comment: @luk32 Yeah maybe I'm cheap on the wrong spot :-). In order to address the whole Unicode range a char32_t is enough. But I also want to support UTF-16 and maybe in the future UTF-8. When I use char32_t as UCD id I also must to a convertion of UTF-16 to UTF-32 first....

Comment: You should rather think how to deal with "holes" so you don't `<hint>`map`</hint>` unnecessary values. As you say, the whole coding space is 4Gi big but "only" ~128Ki slots are used.

Comment: The problem with code that isn't C++ is that it is nonsense; "is this possible"; you need to spend more time describing your actual problem.  You are storing an *entire unicode character database of every UTF-16 code point in memory*?  That sounds suspect; what actual use case is there for that?  If you want random access to the code units of variable size, you'll have to *work* for it.  What would you compare an entire database **to**?!  Please make your actual problem statement clearer, and include sample use cases.

Comment: The non-working code is also undocumented: `m_arrData` is textbook horrible variable name.  `CUT` undocumented.  No sample use of the type (is that supposed to be an array of unicode points, or is that a surrogate thing, or what?), either construction *or* what you want it to do.  I mean, "I want to pack read only unicode into a continguous buffer and be able to iterate over it by code point and by raw memory and have reasonably fast random access to by code point index and raw memory index" is a problem statement.  You'd use view types and a sparse skip list or something.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible?

No.

> I see it as a pImpl idom without the pointers because they will also take up to much memory on my 64 bits machine.

There is no 64-bit platform where you are so strapped for memory that you cannot include another pointer.

You can't scope the `typedef` to a constructor and somehow have it persist with class scope.

Since the size/layout/members of the class depends on the parameter, the class itself needs to be parameterized.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I was already afraid of this answer. The reason I'm stressing the memory is because 8 bytes( 64 bits) per character is way to much even on an x64. This means that even when using UTF-8 with plain Latin characters will be expensive in memory size.

Comment: I would just use UTF-32 as your in-memory representation and discard this class altogether.